# Log-Log slope to visually identical linear slope,

Tags: logarithms, graphing-functions, slope

I need to plot segments with Log-Log slopes (1, -1, 05 and 0.25), on a linear graphic.
How to convert these slopes to a linear graphic, so that they look the same?

I have as only information :   *Log(x)/Log(y) = slope*

But I haven't been able to do something that works, all my tests failed, for example :

```
newSlope = Exp(Y) * (X^slope)
```

Comment: You should post the exercise verbatim.

Comment: It is not an exercice. I'm a developer, and I have to convert a linear abacus into a log log abacus, using the log log slope. But the abacus is drawn in screen coordinates, which are linear.

Comment: All I can can do here is to solve the equation  $\log(x )/ \log(y) = \textrm{slope}$ for y. 1.  $\log(x ) = \log(y)\cdot \textrm{slope}$. 2.$\frac1{\textrm{slope}}\log(x )   = \log(y)$ 3. $y=e^{\frac1{\textrm{slope}}\log(x ) }$ 4. $y=x^{\frac1{\textrm{slope}} }$ One question I have is the following: What are the names of the axes of the new graph?